# splitting a time period into calendar months -- mysql

Tags: mysql

I am basically facing the same problem as described in this thread: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Oracle/10.x/Q_24693813.html. The difference is that I need to find a solution with **MYSQL**.

I am dealing with an Electricity Usage table:

```
ID     Account   FromDate      ToDate       ElecUse   ElecDemand  ElecBillAmt
2903   100009    2010-10-14    2010-11-12   352400    668.1       12592.53
2904   100009    2010-11-12    2010-12-15   426400    666         14284.39
2905   100009    2010-12-15    2010-01-14   406800    708.4       13812.54
2906   100009    2010-01-14    2010-02-15   443200    697.9       14514.99
```

I would like to report the usage on a monthly basis beginning with the start of each month and ending with the end of each month. Thus, I would like to have a MYSQL query that can produce the following table from the above:

```
Account   FromDate      ToDate        ElecUse    ElecDemand    ElecBillAmt
100009    2010-10-14    2010-10-31    206579     391.51        7381.74
100009    2010-11-01    2010-11-30    378402     639.24        13002.12
100009    2010-12-01    2010-12-31    410778     680.46        13859.46
100009    2011-01-01    2011-01-31    425290     701.14        14156.77
100009    2011-02-01    2011-02-15    207750     327           6803.85
```

I appreciate the help,
Dan

Comment: It seems that you're looking for some kind of interpolation of the costs. Linearly interpolating the use data seems do-able.  HOWEVER, `ElecDemand` is an instantaneous peak-load measurement. It's not obvious how to assign it to a particular calendar month.  It certainly makes no sense to try to interpolate it as if it was usage.  Have you tried any SQL queries?

Answer (score 0):

Turning columns into rows is often the job of a self-join or a union.

In all of your examples, your FromDate is the month before the ToDate.  How about one query to get the number of days in the first month, and another to get the leftover days in the second month?  Allocating ElecUse between the two would be easy after that.

Based on your actual data, you might need more queries (the two dates are in the same month, etc).

```
select fromdate, last_day(fromdate) as todate,
  datediff(last_day(fromdate), fromdate) as days_in_month,
  datediff(todate, fromdate) as days_in_range,
  datediff(last_day(fromdate), fromdate)/datediff(todate, fromdate) as pct_in_month,
  elecuse * (datediff(last_day(fromdate), fromdate)/datediff(todate, fromdate)) as elecuse_in_month
...
```

I left in the intermediate columns so you could see what was going on:

```
+------------+------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+------------------+
| fromdate   | todate     | days_in_month | days_in_range | pct_in_month | elecuse_in_month |
+------------+------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+------------------+
| 2010-10-14 | 2010-10-31 |            17 |            29 |       0.5862 |      206579.3102 |
+------------+------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+------------------+
```

UNION that with another query that does the second month in the original row's range, and you should be all set.

Heed @OllieJones' warnings about ElecDemand, though.